# How to use the phrase through the "eyes of"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases

I want to say that I am writing this article to understand the concepts of Set-top from the angle of Broad-com. Can I say the following -

This brings an end to the topic of "Set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom".

or

This brings an end to the topic of " Understanding of Set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom."

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking (which makes me agree with the existing close vote). I believe that you don't want us to address the part *This brings an end to the topic of*, but only this part: *"Set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom"*. In effect, you are asking if *"Set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom"* is good as the title of a topic. Or at least that's the best I can guess. My feeling is that "through the eyes" is fine, adding "understanding" will make it sound odd, and *set-top boxes* would be better than *set-top*.

Comment: Yes, this is my question and you have answered. Perhaps, you can add in the answer. Thus,I can accept and close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the OP's clarification in a comment, the OP is asking if **Set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom** is good as the title of a topic, with another alternative: *Understanding of set-top through the eyes of a chip vendor - Broadcom*.

Short answer: Yes, *through the eyes* is good as is.

**[Through someone's eyes](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/eye_1#eye_1__82)** is a common phrase, meaning "as though a particular person is seeing or experiencing something". *"X through the eyes of Broadcom"* basically means *"X, as Broadcom sees it"*. Thus, the OP's usage is correct. Adding *understanding of* is unnecessary, and, in my opinion, makes it sound awkward.

Another minor point is that the more common term is *set-top box*, not just *set-top*. So, here is the title of the topic I'd recommend (I believe that using a hyphen is okay, but I'm more familiar with using a comma):

> ***Set-top boxes through the eyes of a chip vender, Broadcom***

Answer (score 0):

I think *in the eyes of...* is used for a person and not any website/inanimate objects. Though I cannot make out what exactly you want to tell, here is my *try* (If I understood you correctly!) -

> This brings an end to the topic "A 'Set-Top' (topic) According to Broad.Com"

*"According to..."* works well in such contexts.

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Ah, now you are using 'through the eyes!'